# Preferred method for raising Python Exception from many codepaths?

Tags: python, exception, pytest

I am writing code in Python, using PyTest for testing.

Suppose I am performing some task that may fail in many possible ways. I have a function that performs this task, and counts the number of times each of these failure conditions are met. I also have a test suite that tests each component of the task by providing particular inputs, and asserts that the expected failure type occurs. I wish to have a string description of each unique error, so that the output that maps a failure condition to its frequency is descriptive and easily human-readable. What is the best method for accomplishing this?

I have thought of two methods.

**Method 1**

```
class SuperException(Exception):

    description = "A SuperException was thrown"

class CustomException1(SuperException):

    description = "Exception 1 was thrown"

class CustomException2(SuperException):

    description = "Exception 2 was thrown"

def func1(x):
    if x:
        raise CustomException1()
    raise CustomException2()

def method1():
    try:
        func1(True)
    except SuperException as exc:
        print(exc.description)

def test_func1():
    pytest.raises(func1,True,CustomException1)
    pytest.raises(func1,False,CustomException2)
```

Here, I create a super class for all of the exceptions, and give it a "description" field. I then create a subclass for every type of exception that could be thrown (every failure condition). I then run the task, and catch all errors of type SuperException. I can then access the details of the exception using exc.description in the except block. I can also test the functionality of the task using pytest through a series of pytest.raises function calls as shown.

This method appears clean, although it feels very cumbersome to define a new class for every failure condition (there will be many).

**Method 2**

```
class CustomEnum(str,Enum):
    error1 = "First error"
    error2 = "Second error"

class ExceptionError(Exception):
    """An exceptional error"""

def func2(x):
    if x:
        raise ExceptionError(CustomEnum.error1)
    else:
        raise ExceptionError(CustomEnum.error2)

def method2():
    try:
        func2(True)
    except ExceptionError as exc:
        print(exc.args[0].value)

def test_func2():
    with pytest.raises(ExceptionError) as excinfo:
        func1(True)
    assert excinfo.args[0] == CustomEnum.error1
```

Here, I use only one exception class. I pass the string description of the error to the exception as an Enum. I can catch that error, and access the failure information from exc.args[0].value . The testing is a little bit more cumbersome, as shown. However, adding new failure conditions is less awkward than creating a new class each time, and I simply need to add one line to the enum class.

Which of these methods would be better? Why so? Is there another method that is better than both of these?

Edit: A potential simplification of the problem I mentioned in a comment:

What is the best way to store these descriptive strings in the raised Exceptions? Through "description" fields from a subclass, or through the args list of the exception, whose value will be set to an Enum that holds the unique string values. Or, to use something other than exceptions entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is more verbose but it's preferred if you want to actually catch some of your custom exceptions since method 2 will ONLY raise `ExceptionError`.

Edit: After reading your comments to me it's clear that you should go with method 1:

```
class CustomException1(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Exception 1 was thrown")

class CustomException2(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Exception 2 was thrown")

try:
    raise CustomException1
except CustomException1 as e:
    print("Caught custom exception 1")

try:
    raise Exception("Some other exception")
except CustomException1 as e:
    print("Caught custom exception 1")
```

this makes it easy to only catch the exceptions you want without needing to mess with string comparisons, etc.

Comment: I only care about the unique string description of the error that occurred from a given codepath, and was using exceptions to store these string descriptions in one way or another. I have no other use case for the exceptions in this module, and would only catch them for the two reasons listed above: 1. Counting how often each one occurs, and 2: testing the functions to ensure they raise the expected exception (reach the expected codepath) when given particular inputs.

Comment: `method*` will really be that general. It call the main function with some inputs, catch all exceptions, and then do some work that depends on which exception was raised from `func*`. I guess the question really boils down to: What is the best way to store these descriptive strings in the raised Exceptions? Through "description" fields from a subclass, or through the args list of the exception, whose value will be set to an Enum that holds the unique string values. Or, to use something other than exceptions entirely.

Comment: @pluto_projector see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the better formulation of the `CustomException*` classes, I see now that it is better to use the built-in message functionality as opposed to defining my own description field, even if this does make the class definitions even clunkier. 

I will never be catching my `CustomException*` classes in the business logic, only in the testing. In the business logic, I only catch the super class and then check the message of the actual error that was thrown. Nonetheless, I think you are correct in suggesting method 1, as it is much cleaner to access the message of the exception.

Comment: @pluto_projector even for testing, why not just check the type of exception? that'll be much faster AND cleaner than comparing the messages. Edit: I hate the term "business logic". I hear it everywhere and despite working for a financial firm, I still don't understand what "business logic" actually means. Any logic is "business logic" ...

Comment: On second thought, is it cleaner to create the exception classes as you present them? I originally thought it was when I saw your answer because it is more natural for str(exc) to return the exception message as opposed to remembering that exceptions of my custom type have a .description field. But, I could just define _\_str_\_ in the super exception class as returning description, and then all subclasses only have to be defined with the custom field description, and would not require all of the repetitive, clunky boilerplate code of creating an _\_init_\_ method and using super().

Comment: Yes, I do check the type of the exception during testing. Using method 1, a test using PyTest's `pytest.raises` would look like `pytest.raises(func1,True,CustomException1)`